# Php problems with characters

Tags: php, postgresql, character-encoding

I am building an app with Apache cordova for the support team for my company and everything was ok when I was using a test database in UTF8 was working.

Then when I was implement the real db I notice it was encoded with win-1252.

The problem is, even the db is with win-1252 we have many rows using special caracters like "ç" and "~" and "´" and "`" and with that when I am running the php all rows in the tables in my db will not show becasue of that.

Keep in mind I cann't convert the db to utf8.

ps:The solution I see is go to each row and remove that caracters but isn't a good solution(about 20,000 rows)

........................

PHP file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=bdgestclientes2 
    user=postgres password=postgres") 
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

$data=array();

$q=pg_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idcliente = 3");
```

$row=pg_fetch_object($q)){$data[]=$row};

echo json_encode($data);

Comment: You have a database in which you want to store characters it does not support. That's the issue you should be fixing. Yes, there are workarounds, no, the real issue is that the database doesn't support the characters you need it to support.

Comment: What you could do if you absolutely cannot change the character set is to convert your strings to base64 when saving and convert them back to UTF-8 when loading

Comment: The thing is the database is encoded with win1252 and I have like 20000 rows, and something like 2000 rows that have any kind of special caracters.



$data=array();
$q=pg_query($dbconn,"SELECT * from clients where idclient = 3");
while ($row=pg_fetch_object($q)) {
  $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);




in this query I am testing with client 3 and in his name he has a "ç" so if I run the php i will not get any results, but when i change in db "ç" for "c" it show all the row data.
The thing is there is any convert method while I run the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add a line in php to encode to unicode so I could use the data and display the way it is

```
pg_set_client_encoding($dbconn, "UNICODE");
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a problem at all.

[Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) supports “ç” (code point 0xE7), “~” (code point 0x7E), “`” (code point 0x60) and “´” (code point 0xB4).

PostgreSQL will automatically convert the characters to the database encoding.

You will get problems if you want to store characters that do *not* occur in Windows-1252, like “Σ”.
In that case, the correct solution is to use a database with a different encoding (UTF8).

If you cannot do that, you'll have to store the strings as binary objects (data type [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)) and handle encoding in your application. That will only work well if you don't need to process these functions in the database (e.g., use an index for case insensitive search).

Comment: I search and I found that conclusion, but the thing is. If I do a simple query in a php file to acess to database and run the query (Select name From clients where idcliente = 3) and his name is for example "Gonçalves" the query will not show any result. but if I go manually to the database and change his name to "Goncalves" it works fine and that is where I get lost why he isn't displaying the table with "ç" in this case

Comment: You don't show any code, so it is impossible to say. The query most assuredly *will* have a result, but your PHP code may be unable to handle or display it correctly.

Comment: <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=bdgestclientes2 user=postgres password=postgres") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

$data=array();
$q=pg_query($dbconn,"SELECT * from clientes where idcliente = 3");
while ($row=pg_fetch_object($q)) {
  $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>

this is the code I am using in php file

Comment: **Please**, edit the question and post the code there. In a comment, the code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, where I cannot modify the database setup, but I use php's html entity encode to work around:

I removed the html key elements from the native htmlentities because I work with wysiwyg editors and need to keep the content like that. If you have no such limitations you can just use htmlentities on the string.

```
function makeFriendly($string)
        $list = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
        unset($list['"']);
        unset($list['\'']);
        unset($list['<']);
        unset($list['>']);
        unset($list['&']);
        $search = array_keys($list);
        $replace = array_values($list);
        $search = array_map('utf8_encode', $search);
        str_replace($replace, $search, $string);
}
```

If I need the actual characters I can always call html_entity_decode on the database string to get the 'real' string.